# Chained imports from a subdirectory

Tags: python

Given the following directory tree:

```
-- dir
  |-- main.py
  |-- subdir
    |-- __init__.py
    |-- first.py
    |-- second.py
```

I want to import `second.py` in `first.py` and `first.py` in `main.py`. However I still want to be able to execute `first.py` standalone.

In `main.py` using `import subdir.first` and `import subdir.second` works flawlessly, however, if `first.py` imports `second.py` there is a problem:

- If `first.py` is executed separately (`__name__ == '__main__'`) the import can be just `import second` (as it’s in the same directory). Importing this version into `main.py` results in an error: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'third'`
- If `first.py` is imported by `main.py` but should itself import `second.py` the import must be `import subdir.second` or `from . import second`. That way `first.py` cannot be executed separately, as `subdir.second` doesn’t exist in its own folder.

Is there a neat way to import `second.py` in `first.py` and being able to both execute `fist.py` on its own as well as import `first.py` into `main.py`?

Comment: You should have the same PYTHONPATH to execute both main and first. Then the import should be the same for both and you will not have those errors.

Comment: Wouldn't altering the PYTHONPATH make the code unusable on other machines where the scripts may reside in a differently named folder? Or is that variable only set on runtime?